# Delete duplicate entries in extremely big Database

Tags: mysql

Last week I accidentally introduced a bug in our website, and it kept reporting errors when receiving data to insert in the Database, although it was correctly adding the new entry. As such, the information kept being sent and it kept reporting there had been an error writing on the database and writing on it, duplicating every entry between a few dozens of times to a few hundreds. I don't know why the loop stopped but it eventually gave an OK, and stopped writing.

I didn't understand that the error came from my code at first so it took me a couple of days to solve it, meanwhile our database kept being bombarded and flooded.

In hindsight I didn't handle this very well, I am aware, but I would like to fix what I have screwed.

I have been searching the Stack for ways to clean duplicate rows and there are dozens of questions and answers for it, so I frankensteined a solution that seems to work.

```
DELETE FROM app_info
WHERE  `idinfo` NOT IN (SELECT minid
                        FROM   (SELECT Min(`idinfo`) AS minid
                                FROM   app_info
                                GROUP  BY `when`,
                                          `idbooth`,
                                          `iddongle`,
                                          `typeinfo`,
                                          `money`,
                                          `money2`,
                                          `currency`,
                                          `stock`,
                                          `i1`,
                                          `i2`,
                                          `i3`,
                                          `i4`,
                                          `i5`,
                                          `str1`,
                                          `str2`,
                                          `pbnew`,
                                          `in1`,
                                          `in2`,
                                          `in3`,
                                          `in4`,
                                          `in5`,
                                          `in6`,
                                          `in7`,
                                          `in8`) e)
       AND `idinfo` < 1545000
       AND `idinfo` > 1541500;
```

This works, but I have to be doing brackets of ids, and limit the search there, otherwise it takes too long and cancels before doing anything. Even doing so, it takes 3 or 4 minutes where the website stops working (the database is too busy, I guess), and it will take me ages to clean the DB.

I have been thinking of a way to streamline this and I thought that I could search for all individual entries starting from the day I introduced, grouping them, and make a list, then I could maybe make a php file that looped through the list searching for all entries that correspond to that item in the list and deleting all but one.

I have tried, making the list it's easy, I think:

```
SELECT *  FROM  `App_info`  
WHERE  `when` >  '2018-11-05' 
GROUP BY  `typeInfo` ,  `str2`  
ORDER BY  `App_info`.`when` ASC
```

But I have not been able to reformulate my first query to take into account the info that the second generates. At first I supposed that substituing the "WHEN" that I used to make brackets by the info on the fields I grouped by in the second query would help, but if I do it like that I get 0 rows, so it does nothing.

Also depending on the entry selected, if it has too many copies like the ones that have hundreds, it crashes the database anyway... So it doesn't seem to be the solution I was looking for.

I don't know what to try anymore. How can I clean the duplicate entries when they are so many in number, without crashing the database? I guess that hogging the DB will be inevitable, but I can just issue a downtime for maintenance, so it would not be a problem.

Comment: Thanks for formatting it

Comment: I think you are missing `Having COUNT(*) > 1` in the subquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using a temporary table to store the duplicate IDs.

1. Use your select query that gives you the duplicate ids to be deleted but insert the records into a new table. With the group by this may take a while but will not lock the database.
2. Run whatever tests you need to verify that the temp table contains only the IDs that need to be deleted.
3. In a maintenance window, after a backup, run a delete where ID in (select ID from temp_table).
4. If this is still too long, you can do them in batches from the temp table.

The major advantage is that you're not running that big heavy query on your table while at the same time locking the table for deletes, which may even cause a deadlock.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to accept an answer. I was quite busy last week. This is what helped me most, thank you! I could do it in an hour approx, had to break it in a few batches but not as many as how I was doing earlier. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Efficiently, you may utilize the `INSERT IGNORE` query. The steps:

- Create a temporary table similar with similar schema to the existing
  table.
- Add `UNIQUE` constraint to the columns we want.
- Run `INSERT IGNORE` to copy data from the original table to the temporary table. This way, any duplicate rows will not be inserted into the temporary table because they violate the `UNIQUE` constraint (which was already ignored).
- Rename the original table to something else and rename the temporary
  table to the original table.
- Drop the redundant table.

Hope this helps.